# Where does echo end up when a php script is executed from a shell script?

Tags: ubuntu, php, php-cli

I have a php script that I execute from a .sh file, and have some echoes in it.

if I run the script from the terminal, I can see all the output, but where does it go when it is running in the background?

Is it getting logged somewhere?

To clarify: I do not care about the output I just want to know if it goes away, or getting stored somewhere somehow.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you start the script so that it runs in the background to begin with? Is it from a cronjob, do you use the & operator of your shell, or something totally different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, because your PHP CLI command is executed within your shell script, the output is sent to the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` output streams.

Where the output is sent from there depends on how your script is invoked, for example on a standard terminal the output is sent to the terminal itself.